# autostart x server in Lubuntu, login loop

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, xorg, login, autostart

On Ubuntu 18.04, I was able to `sudo startx` in `~/.bashrc`. The system would boot into my GUI program in `~/.xinitrc`, without asking for password(I'd checked auto-login when I installed Ubuntu) or even displaying GNOME.

I did the same thing on Lubuntu 18.04. However, I just got stuck on a login loop. If I `CTRL+ALT+F1` and login through the virtual terminal my program runs, but I don't want to have to do that.

What exactly is going on? Is there another way I can achieve what I did with Ubuntu?

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First setup to boot in text mode:

in `/etc/default/grub`: comment the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and set

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

save.

Then setup auto login:

```
sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

in `getty@tty1`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/sbin/agetty --autologin <username> --noclear %I $TERM
```

save and reboot.